# Running benchmarks without "go test" in golang

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

I want to run the benchmarks in my application. Is that possible? If so, how can I? I have been looking around but haven't seen any indication so far.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [testing.Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) without running `go test`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func Fib(n int) int {
    if n <= 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n == 1 {
        return 1
    }
    return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
}

func main() {
    res := testing.Benchmark(func(b *testing.B) {
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            Fib(10)
        }
    })
    fmt.Println(res)
    // (on my mac)
    // 3000000               454 ns/op
}
```